# DELETE and EDIT with row in tableView in swift

Tags: swift4

I'm trying to make a slide edit and del button on row. However, it is not working. The button doesn't show up at all and i try lots of example online. The Code to generate the button is in the bottom of my code.

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {code.................}
extension DetailViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
{
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, view, handler) in
        //YOUR_CODE_HERE
        print("HELLO")
    }
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])

    return configuration
}


}
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: i am thinking the problem may from here class DetailViewController: UIViewController {code.................}
extension DetailViewController: UITableViewDataSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  class DetailViewController: UIViewController {code.................}
  //inside (code......) we have to add
  sensorTableView.delegate = self
  sensorTableView.dataSource = self
```

i still have no idea what is the code mean but this will be work if slide button have no reaction

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
tableView(_:editActionsForRowAt:)
```

implement

```
tableView(_:trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)
```

Comment: i tried this. This is not work  doesnt have anything show up

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?{         code.....(noting happen)          }